# Install SQL server 2008 R2 with VS 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Ok, I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm trying to add a "SQL Server Database" to an ASP MVC project.

But it keeps telling me I need SQL Server for it to work.
What do I need to do to setup the SQL Server properly for it to work with VS2010 ?

I've tried messing with the SQL Server Management Studio, and can't seem to connect to anything through there.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I create a working SQL service ?

Comment: I think the main problem is that I can't find where I create a new database. The service isn't even running yet :/

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 .. Was downloaded from MS site which was supposed to be express..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that the service wasn't running at all.

I've reinstalled it, and it worked OK.

Then you need to connect with the manager to **(local)\SQLSERVEREXPRESS**

And in VS2010 go to **Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Database Connections**
Enter **SQLSERVEREXPRESS** as the connection name.

Of course if you changed the name (in the install process), use the new name

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to add a file-based SQL Server database, which requires SQL Express. If you want to use SQL Server 2008 (as opposed to the Express edition), the database will not exist within the project; your project will have a connection string that points to the database.

Comment: I think the main problem is that I can't find where I create a new database. The service isn't even running yet :/